# How to open app in the Enterprise Browser?

Tags: browser, enterprise

I have a website with a payment link like this: [sumupmerchant://pay/1.0?affiliate-key=aa&app-id=bb&total=0&currency=EUR&title=cc](http://sumupmerchant://pay/1.0?affiliate-key=aa&app-id=bb&total=0&currency=EUR&title=cc) and when i open this URL in Google Chrome on my android device, it opens the app which is installed on the device. The Enterprise Browser doesn't open it (it shows a webpage not available error). Is there anyone who knows if it's possible to open another app from within the enterprise browser?

If it was possible to use the Chrome browser then i would but it's not possible since we have a webapp which needs this browser to make a connection with a Zebra printer.

Thank you in advance.

Pim

Answer (score 1):

Is this Zebra's Enterprise Browser?  If so, although you can't open apps by clicking on links there is an Intent API available and you could say something like this:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="ebapi-modules.js"></script>
    var params = {
        intentType: EB.Intent.START_ACTIVITY,
        action: 'pay',
        appName: 'com.company.sumupmerchant',
        data: {"afilliate_key":"aa", "app-id":"bb","total":"0","currency":"EUR","title":"cc"}
    EB.Intent.send(params);
```

*I'm not sure exactly how to launch your app via Intent, the above is just a guess*.  More on the Intent API at https://techdocs.zebra.com/enterprise-browser/2-5/api/Intent/